# Requirejs синтаксис

Tags: javascript

Поясните, пожалуйста, разницу между:

```
requirejs.config({
} });
```

и

```
require.config({
});
```

А также между:

```
requirejs(['foo'], function   (foo) {
});
```

и

```
require(['foo'], function(foo) {
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert(require === requirejs) // true говорит нам о том, что разницы нет
```